# How to select the first occurence of a word using java regex package.a

Tags: java, regex

I am creating a notepad using java and awt package. A problem that i am facing is the find utility in notepad. It selects the last occurrence of the word. Suppose i write "go" in text field and click "find next" button and i have two occurrences of word "go" in the file then it will select the second one but i want it to select the first occurrence.
Here is the code for find next event.

```
else if(act=="Find Next")
{   
    String str=t.getText();
    pt=Pattern.compile(t1.getText());
    m=pt.matcher(str.replace("\n", ""));
    while(m.find())
        t.select(m.start(),m.end());
    f.toFront();
}
```

here is the file that i tested it on.

```
this is sample file just to test the notepad application.
what could possibly go wrong go.
```

the code selects the second occurrence of "go". What can be the possible solution.

Comment: Hint: it does not select the *second* occurrence but always the *last* one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a `while` loop here?

> ```
> while(m.find())
>     t.select(m.start(),m.end());
> ```

For each match, it will select it.
As a result, the last one will get selected.

To select the first one, change the `while` to `if`:

```
if (m.find())
    t.select(m.start(),m.end());
```

To select the *next* one, you will need a way to track the current position. Because "next" is a relative term,
you need to define *next from what*.